# Clear selectedRows after deleting records in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

I am trying to clear the selected rows after a deletion action. The delete actions works perfectly. After the Delete from APEX, it performs a refreshApex() which works fine too.

However, the checked rows that where before deletion are still checked in the same position, but in the remaining records in the list.

I need to achieve a function that allows me to set the selected rows to empty, or to reset this attribute of the data-table.

I have tried using a custom id and using getelementById, but doesn't work. Neither of the other solutions I found for the aura:component. I am using pure LWC.

Before Delete:

[image: Before deleting record]

After Deleting

[image: After Deleting]

As it is seen in the image it maintains the position of the checked as it was before deleting.

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" class="slds-p-top_x-large">
        <div slot="title" class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col--padded ">
                <h2>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:delegated_account" size="small">
                    </lightning-icon>
                    &nbsp;Developments
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col-padded">
                <lightning-button name="addDevelopmentBtn" label="Add" onclick={clickAddDevelopment}
                    icon-name="utility:add" alternative-text="Add" title="Add Development">
                </lightning-button>
                <lightning-button data-id="dev-table" name="deleteDevelopmentBtn" label="Delete"
                    onclick={clickDeleteDevelopment} icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="Delete"
                    title="Delete Development">
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <template if:true={developments}>
            <lightning-datatable data={developments} columns={columns} key-field="id" onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                onrowselection={getSelectedRows}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    track,
    wire,
    api
} from 'lwc';
import {
    NavigationMixin
} from 'lightning/navigation'
import
getAreaItems
from '@salesforce/apex/areaItemsController.getAreaItems'
import
deleteAreaItems
from '@salesforce/apex/areaItemsController.deleteAreaItems'
import {
    deleteRecord
} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {
    ShowToastEvent
} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import {
    refreshApex
} from '@salesforce/apex';

const actions = [{
        label: 'View Details',
        name: 'show_details'
    },
    {
        label: 'Delete',
        name: 'delete_dev'
    }
]
const columns = [{
        label: 'Development Name',
        fieldName: 'sonn_ait_Development_Name__c'
    }, {
        label: 'Sonneil Reference',
        fieldName: 'sonn_ait_Sonneil_Reference_Development__c'
    },
    {
        label: 'Available Units',
        fieldName: 'sonn_ait_NumOfUnits__c'
    },
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: actions,
        }
    }
]



export default class areaInterestUnitsList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId
    @track developments = [];
    @track areas = [];
    selectedRows = [];
    fullAreaItems;
    columns = columns;
    error;



    @wire(getAreaItems, {
        areaId: '$recordId'
    })
    getfullAreaItems(result) {
        this.fullAreaItems = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.developments = this.getDevelopments(result.data);
            this.areas = result.data;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            console.log(this.error);
        }
    }

    getDevelopments(listOfItems) {

        let devs = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < listOfItems.length; i++) {
            switch (listOfItems[i].sonn_ait_Item_Type__c) {
                case 'Development':
                    devs.push(listOfItems[i]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return devs;

    }

    getSelectedRows(e) {
        this.selectedRows = e.detail.selectedRows;
        this.template.getElementById("dev-table").getSelectedRows();
    }

    clickAddDevelopment(e) {
        console.log('click add dev');
    }

    async clickDeleteDevelopment(e) {
        let idsToDelete = [];

        this.selectedRows.forEach(element => {
            idsToDelete.push(element.Id);
            console.log(element);
        });

        await this.bulkDeleteItems(idsToDelete);
        this.clearCheckedItems();


    }

    bulkDeleteItems(itemIds) {

        if (itemIds.length == 0) {
            this.showToast('No items to delete', 'Please select items from the list in order to be removed', 'error');
            return;
        }

        deleteAreaItems({
            areaItemsId: itemIds
        }).then(() => {
            this.showToast('Area Items Deleted Succesfully', 'All items deleted succesfully', 'success');
            this.refreshItems();
        }).catch(error => {
            this.showToast('Something went wrong', error.body.message, 'error');
            return;
        });

    }

    clearCheckedItems() {
     // THIS IS THE FUNCTION I NEED TO ACHIEVE
    }

    handleRowAction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const row = event.detail.row;

        switch (actionName) {
            case 'show_details':
                this.navigateToRecordViewPage(row.sonn_ait_development__c)
                break;
            case 'delete_dev':
                deleteRecord(row.Id).then(() => {
                        this.showToast('Area Item Deleted', 'The item has been succesfully removed from the interest area', 'success');
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.showToast('Something went wrong', error.body.message, 'error');
                        return;
                    }).then(() => {
                        this.refreshItems();
                    });


                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    refreshItems() {
        return refreshApex(this.fullAreaItems); //refreshApex only works on the raw object provided by wire directly
    }

    navigateToRecordViewPage(recordId) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: recordId,
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    deleteAreaItem(recordId) {
        deleteRecord(recordId);

    }

}
```

Apex just performs a SOQL action of deleting from DDBB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** As you already have an attribute named `selectedRows`, you need to use a new attribute something else, like `setSelectedRows` you need to use two different attributes to store the selected rows and to reset the selected.

Create one attribute for the selected rows and assign it to `[]` an empty array, whenever you want to unselect the selected rows.

```html
<lightning-datatable 
    data={developments}
    columns={columns}
    key-field="id"
    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
    onrowselection={getSelectedRows}
    selected-rows={setSelectedRows}
></lightning-datatable>
```

You will need a reactive property for this.

```js
selectedRows = [];

...

bulkDeleteItems(itemIds) {
    if (itemIds.length == 0) {
        this.showToast(
            'No items to delete',
            'Please select items from the list in order to be removed',
            'error'
        );
        return;
    }

    deleteAreaItems({
        areaItemsId: itemIds
    }).then(() => {
        this.showToast(
            'Area Items Deleted Succesfully',
            'All items deleted succesfully',
            'success'
        );
        this.refreshItems();
        this.setSelectedRows = []; /// empty selection.
    }).catch(error => {
        this.showToast('Something went wrong', error.body.message, 'error');
        return;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul. Not sure if I'm implementing this right. But if I do this, then the data-table just doesn't let check anything. Whenever you check it remains unchecked.

Comment: Ohh I see, Its because you are using the same attribute to store the selected rows. I will just update the in answer

Comment: updated the answer, you can use `setSelectedRows` instead of `selectedRows` as you need two separate attributes here.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot. Works perfectly. That was an easy solution I just wasn't able to figure out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually have to set the `selected-rows` attribute of the `lightning-datatable` in the template.  You can simply clear its value in JavaScript like this:

```js
this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').selectedRows = [];
```